# Хочу сделать Android приложение-клиент для сайта

Tags: android, jsoup

Проблема в том, что я не могу понять, какую технику мне применять. Парсинг через JSOUP или через WebView элемент. У сайта нет адаптивной разметки для мобильных устройств - это проблема. С сайта необходимо получать-передавать данные. На сайте имеется регистрация. Прошу знатоков помочь советом или примером. Спасибо.

Comment: вопросы-опросники запрещены. Большой уже, сам решай.

Comment: Если нет верстки для мобилок и это кретично, значит нужно делать нормальное полноценное приложение. Если не кретично значит WebView

Answer (score 2):

Сайт-то ваш или чужой? Если чужой, то парсить (желательно своим сервером, а не с мобильного клиента), если свой, то лучше сделать API. Приложение, состоящее из webview для сайта полезно только с одной точки зрения - для развода клиента на деньги, практического смысла в нем нет.

Comment: Сайт чужой. Просто часто им пользуюсь и хочется всегда иметь быстрый доступ к необходимой информации. Спасибо за совет.